# Amplifier supply voltage difference

Tags: power-supply, voltage, amplifier

Is it possible that a slight voltage difference between voltage rails of a symmetrical supply can make noise if connected to an amplifier?

If yes, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Highly unlikely. Please post a schematic.

Comment: Possibly ... "offsets" voltages.

Comment: Can you explain what type of "noise" you are concerned about? Is this audible noise, high frequency or low frequency, RF noise, noise causing functional errors? Do you have access to an oscilloscope to view this noise? You need to include additional info to get an adequate response.

Comment: It is possible but also there might not be any relation between the two. Maybe there is some other problem.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and can't be a personal tutorial service. This is a two-line question that asks for far more effort in reply. Please edit your question (don't post info in comments) and add plenty of detail on what you are doing and why. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it can attract. Thanks.

Comment: No.  By itself, a voltage difference in the power rails does not cause noise in an amplifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  [this](https://shop.griederbauteile.ch/info/l/LF13741.pdf)

[image]

noise can be induced. Note that the PSSR is measured with both sides of power supplies changing.

From [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110), here is an example ...

[image]

If this is "noise", it can be make "noise" at the output of an amplifier.

Here is the effect of a square voltage around Vcc= 15 V. Resulting noise is 116 uV peak to peak.

[image]

Here is another simulation (change of value of R6, added R-C decoupling).

[image]